# Plot duplication in Pandas Plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis

There is an issue with the plot() function in Pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'])
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1., 1, 0., 0), loc=2 , prop={'size':6})
```

This will make a plot with too many lines. Note however that half will be on top of each other. It seems to have something to do with the axis because when I do not use them the issue goes away.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'])
df.plot()
```

#### UPDATE

While not idea for my use case the issue can be fixed by using MultiIndex

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.hstack([ ['left']*2, ['right']*2]), ['A', 'B']*2], names=['High', 'Low'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=columns)
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1., 1, 0., 0), loc=2 , prop={'size':16})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with your duplication of column names, not `ax` at all (if you call `plt.legend` after your second example you see the same extra lines).  Having multiple columns with the same name is confusing the call to `DataFrame.plot_frame`.

If you change your columns to `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` instead, it's fine.

Comment: I realize that it is the duplicate column names which are the source of the issue. Perhaps I should play with MultiIndex a bit. Either way, I tried adding the line and could not produce the same error.

Comment: The difference may have to do with the pandas version. Some of these things fluctuate significantly version to version.

Comment: Weird. In any case, I think this is a bug.